Excel file not opening
I have a macro enabled excel file that hides the application and present a login form and only when the pass is correct it set the application visible to true and the file opens.
Problem is when the password is true I can see the file for a sec and then it’s closed.
What can I do it used to work smoothly all the time and I can’t access the file now
Thank you
Sometimes when I try multiple times to open the file it somehow works again but then the problem comes again next time I try

Do you have something in your code that closes it? Hard to know since you didn't include any.

You could try to troubleshoot the macro code to identify the root cause of the issue and fix it. This could involve reviewing the code line by line, running the macro in debug mode to identify any errors. As you did not provide any code that's  completely up to you. Please take the [tour].

Problem is my code is huge, it would be really hard to track the trigger

Presumably this code is in Sub Workbook_Open() ("I can’t access the file now")
Open up the Workbook preventing that macro from running by holding down the left-shift key when double-clicking the workbook. Keep the shift key depressed until the Workbook is fully open.
Or you could try Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break while the password form is being shown.
Alt-F11 will then get you back into the code. Search for anything that includes .Close or .Quit and place a breakpoint on that line(s). Use Shift-F8 to step through your code to find the point that is closing down the application.
As an aside - if your code is "huge" consider breaking it up into separate subroutines and/or functions so that it easier to read
